# Excel - Numbers of minutes to Time

Tags: excel, date, time

I need to transcribe numbers of minutes in columns of hours and minutes, without using the formatting functions of Excel. The idea is to understand the principle in order to develop it on other larger scale problems.

I have my table with the numbers of minutes, then the columns requested. What are the formulas that can be implemented, especially for the passage from 59 minutes (0:59) to 60 minutes (1:50)?
In image the expected result, but with the values entered manually.

Here a sample:

| Number of minutes | Hour | Minute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 59 | 0 | 59 |
| 60 | 1 | 0 |
| 119 | 1 | 59 |
| 120 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Formula for hours: `=INTEGER(A2/60)`

For minutes: `=A2-(60*B2)`

**UPDATED ANSWER:** If you need days just add some extra basic maths:

[image]

For days formula is: `=INTEGER(A2/1440)`

For hours formula is: `=INTEGER((A2-(B2*1440))/60)`

For minutes formula is: `=A2-(1440*B2)-C2*60`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. 
What if I want to add a "DAY" column (1440 minutes)?

Comment: This is what I had deduced from your answer earlier, unfortunately it does not apply...
If I have 1 minute, I get 0 days, 1 hour and -59 minutes.

Hour=1-(1440*0)=1
For 59 minutes :
Hour=59-(1440*0)=59
And so on...